# matplotlib ticker error on remote cluster

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a Python code that works properly on my local machine. But when I run the same code on a remote cluster I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    from matplotlib import ticker as mtick                  # Import mtick for tick locating and formatting.
  File "/home/nxkr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 158, in <module>
    from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
  File "/home/nxkr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 39, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The source of error is *from matplotlib import ticker as mtick*, but it works properly on my local machine. matplotlib version on both local and remote cluster is 1.4.3. Why does this error occur and how to fix it?

**Update**

When I comment that line I backend_pdf creates the following error:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages    # Import PDF matplotlib backend.
  File "/home/nxkr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 35, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backend_bases import RendererBase, GraphicsContextBase,\
  File "/home/nxkr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 45, in <module>
    import matplotlib.transforms as transforms
  File "/home/nxkr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 39, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: /home/nxkr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_AsEncodedString
```

Commenting that causes pyplot to throw this error:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                         # Import matplotlib for plotting.
  File "/home/nxkr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/home/nxkr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.artist as martist
  File "/home/nxkr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, \
  File "/home/nxkr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 39, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: /home/nxkr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_AsEncodedString
```

Why is that the same version of matplotlib is creating problems on different machines?